# Append list into nested list in a file

Tags: output-formatting, printing

I have a nested list that I use `Put[mylist, file]` to write to a file. I would then like to then append to this nested list some values and add them to the file.

How can I do this without reading the whole file, appending to the list with join, and then writing the list back to the file?

My list looks like

```
element = {"TimeStamp", "140927_1716_23"}, {"Atom Number", 
  621543.}, {"Atom Number Error", 4720.7}, {"Centre Ioffe(mm)", 
  6.66745}, {"Centre Ioffe Error(mm)", 
  0.0052631}, {"Centre UpDown(mm)", 
  1.17768}, {"Centre UpDown Error(mm)", 
  0.00318682}, {"FWHM Ioffe(mm)", 1.68306}, {"FWHM Ioffe Error(mm)", 
  0.0132298}, {"FWHM UpDown(mm)", 1.29802}, {"FWHM UpDown Error(mm)", 
  0.00842762}, {"Background Ioffe", 
  78.9332}, {"Background Ioffe Error", 8.77044}, {"Background UpDown",
   255.325}, {"Background UpDown Error", 11.5685}, {"Trap Type", 
  "Magnetic Trap"}, {"MOT_Loading_Time", 
  10000.}, {"Magnetic_Hold_Time", 50.75}, {"Time_Of_Flight", 
  6.}, {"Exposure_Time", 0.45}

mylist = {element1, element2, ..., elementN}
```

myList is Put into a file. I would like to join more elements into the file (without reading it all joining and rewriting the file).

```
mylist = {element1, element2, ..., elementN, elementN+1}
```

Comment: Maybe [PutAppend](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PutAppend.html)?

Comment: PutAppend just adds to the file, but won't join the new element to the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should re-consider the format you use for storing the data. From the question it is clear that the file is intended to be imported by *Mathematica*. Then why do not use a line-by-line format and then import the file using `ReadList`? You can append the elements of `myList` one-by-one to the `file` using `PutAppend`. Then you can use `ReadList` to get them all back at once as complete `myList`. `ReadList` has excellent performance and is intended to be used exactly for such purposes.

Answer (score 0):

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
element1 = {a, b, c};
mylist = {element1};
Put[mylist, "mylist.txt"];
element2 = {d, e, f};
mylist = Append[mylist, element2];
Put[mylist, "mylist.txt"];
```

You need to save this example before running because of the NotebookDirectory function.

Comment: This writes the whole list every time after its appended too. It might not be very efficient for large lists.